# Let A be an $n\times m$ matrix and B be an $m\times n$ matrix such that AB is invertible. Then which of the following is/are always true?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let A be an $n\times m$ matrix and B be an $m\times n$ matrix. For a square matrix D, let Tr(D) denote trace of D, |D| denote the determinant of D.

Suppose that AB is invertible. Then which of the following is/are always true?

(a) $Tr(AB) = Tr(BA)$.

(b) $|AB| = |BA|$.

(c) $m\geq n$.

(d) BA must be invertible.

For a start, I took several simple matrices, e.g. [1 0], [1 2].

The answer choices I could remove are (b) and (d).

From what I knew, Tr(AB) = Tr(BA) is true for matrices of same order. So, is this true for a general case $n\times m$ and $m\times n$ as well ?

Moreover, I did not expect $m\geq n$ to be true, which seems true using the above example matrices.

How do I solve this properly ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- (a) holds for any $A$ and $B$ such that $AB$ and $BA$ make sense. Just verify both sides of the equality.
- If $m<n$, $B$ has certainly a nontrivial nullspace (rank-nullity theorem) and hence so does $AB$. We would obtain a contradition with the assumption that $AB$ is invertible and hence (c) is true.
- (b) holds if $A$ and $B$ are square ($\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$ for square $A$ and $B$). (d) holds in this case as well (by using (b) and the invertibility of $AB$). However, if $m>n$, then $A$ has a nontrivial nullspace and thus $BA$ is not invertible. In this case, $\det(BA)=0$ and hence (b) does not hold since $\det(AB)\neq 0$ by assumption.